# I'm getting undefined when I try to access to param values using express router

Tags: express

I'm creating a simple Express server, but when I try to move all the HTTP verbs request logic to a separate module I can't access the values of the URL params. My app is comprised of two files, the index.js, and the router file.

This is the code of the index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;
const morgan = require('morgan')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const {dishRouter, dishRouterParams} = require('./routes/dishRouter');

const app = express();
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/dishes', dishRouter)

app.use('/dishes/:dishId', dishRouterParams)

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.end('<html><body><h1>This is an Express Server ;)</h1></body></html>');
});

const server = http.createServer(app)

server.listen(port, hostname, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server running at ${hostname}:${port}`);
});
```

And this is the code of the router file:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const dishRouter = express.Router();

const dishRouterParams = express.Router();

dishRouter.use(bodyParser.json());
dishRouterParams.use(bodyParser.json());

dishRouter
  .route("/")
  .all((req, res, next) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    next();
  })

  .get((req, res, next) => {
    res.end("Will send all the dishes to you");
  })
  .post((req, res, next) => {
    res.end(
      "Will add the dish: " +
        req.body.name +
        " with details: " +
        req.body.description
    );
  })
  .put((req, res, next) => {
    res.statusCode = 403;
    res.end("Put operation not supported on /dishes ");
  })
  .delete((req, res, next) => {
    res.end("Will delete all the dishes! ");
  });

dishRouterParams
  .route("/")
  .all((req, res, next) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    next();
  })
  .get( (req, res, next) => {
    res.end("Sending details of dish: " + req.params.dishId);
  })
  .post( (req, res, next) => {
    res.statusCode = 403;
    res.end("Put operation not supported on /dishes/" + req.params.dishId);
  })
  .put((req, res, next) => {
    res.write("Updating the dish: " + req.params.dishId);
    res.end(
      "Will update the dish: " +
        req.body.name +
        " with details: " +
        req.body.description
    );
  })
  .delete(  (req, res, next) => {
    res.end("Deleting dish: " + req.params.dishId);
  });

module.exports = { dishRouter, dishRouterParams };
```

When I start the server, it works "well" but it says `undefined` for every `req.params.dishId`

Can anyone lend me a hand? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to just one router like `dishRouter` for this approach like this

```
app.use('/dishes', dishRouter)
```

and change the route like this:

```
dishRouter
  .route("/")
  .
  .
  .


dishRouter
  .route("/:dishId")
  .
  .
  .
```